# Extracting yields of decays from fits

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, large-hadron-collider, experimental-technique, particle-detectors

I'm currently reading various papers on the violation of Lepton Flavour Universality in rare B-decays and I would appreciate some help in understanding the methodology for measuring the ratios in these decays.

Here is a quote from a recent [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.09252.pdf) from the LHCb collaboration (p.5):

> An unbinned extended maximum-likelihood fit to the $m(K^+e^+e^−)$ and $m(K^+µ^+µ^−)$
>   distributions of nonresonant candidates is used to determine $R_K$ [the ratio]. In order to take into
>   account the correlation between the selection efficiencies, the different trigger categories
>   and data-taking periods are fitted simultaneously. The resonant decay mode yields are
>   incorporated as constraints in this fit, such that the $B^+\rightarrow K^+µ^+µ^−$ yield and $R_K$ are
>   fit parameters.

My question is how exactly are the yields extracted from the fits performed on the mass data points using maximum likelihood estimations? Does this mean that the fitted function has to be a function of the yield $N$? If yes, how is this achieved?

Comment: This is a well-known method for estimating parameters in the data analysis. If you follow any standard book on statistical method for data analysis in particle physics, more details can be found. Here I can only say the likelihood function will carry an extra PDF for total number of events in the case of extended maximum likelihood as compare to maximum likelihood function. Upon maximizing the likelihood function one can get the parameter of interest.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please recommend a particular textbook?

Answer (score 0):

The book I used to follow "statistical method for data analysis in particle physics by Luca Lista"  and "statistical data analysis by GLEN COWAN" for statistical understanding purposes. 
Besides that, you can follow https://root.cern.ch/ and https://root.cern.ch/guides/roofit-manual s for practical purposes. ROOT is a data analysis software package commonly used by the experimental high energy physics community.  ROOFIT package uses maximum likelihood methods for fitting. How this fitting works, in reality, the mathematical descriptions, etc, you can find from the book.